# Failing to upload an mp4 to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, pydub

I'm trying to convert an WMA file into mp4 in order to upload the file to youtube.
[VN550672.wma.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EmreFRpQjFbXE16jN9YUmkAC3vxEImFB)
Although the conversion is successful (see below) i'm not able to upload the file to youtube. I'm getting the following error

```
The video has failed to process. Please make sure you are uploading a supported file type.
```

[VN550672.mp4.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P-dVXatkgFLARKzQzpAqUYJ9QjeKwzLl)

Any suggestions?

System configuration:
Python version: 3.6.3
Pydub version: 0.22.1
ffmpeg or avlib?: ffmpeg
ffmpeg/avlib version: 2.8.4

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as easy as youtube requires that the media file includes a video stream? The wma file only has a audio stream.

You can try to transcode and add a dummy video stream using

```
ffmpeg -i VN550672.WMA -f lavfi -i color=size=426x240 VN550672.mp4
```

(426x240 is the youtube suggested minimal resolution)

Comment: Thx ! I think that is the problem. will check and update.